# Applying proxy button is not shown

Tags: proxy

In my system whenever I try to apply proxy I never see

"Apply proxy system wide" button

I have seen this problem on some other ubuntu systems too!

What should I do? **[image: How do I apply proxy system-wide]**?

**How do I apply proxy system wide?**

Comment: Did you find any answer as helpful?

Answer (score 0):

**This is normal.** This would happen if you have logged in as a standard user and not as an Administrative user. Standard users don't have access to apply settings system-wide.